# flutter: Content-type must be application/json

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I'm having issues with an http post request. I get the response 'Content-type must be application/json', however I am setting the header to specify the content is of type json.

```
const Map<String, String> header = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

static void init() async {
    var body =
      {
        "username": username, // String username defined above
        "password": password, // String password defined above
      };

    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: header);
    print(response.body);
}
```

As mentioned above, I'm expecting this to work and return a valid json response, however I am receiving an error code of 400, with the message 'Content-type must be application/json'. I'm not quite sure how to fix this, I have used this method to deliver http.Post requests various other times and it has always worked.

Comment: Try with capital T. `Content-Type`

Comment: @Spectarion That didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Is your dash '-' the right dash? Ran into some problems with that before.

Comment: Of note is that `package:http` lower cases all header names before sending them. While this is perfectly legal (see the RFC), it confuses some servers, and has caused other users similar problems. Try the lower level `HttpClient` to prove whether this is the issue. If it is, the you need to get the server to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all those wondering, Richard Heap in the comment above was right, going down to the base HttpClient resolved this issue. (I'm not sure how to credit him with the answer, if someone knows please advise so I can do so).

Below is the code snippet I used to get my code working for documentation purposes

```
static void init() async {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(rawBody)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    var jsonReply = json.decode(reply);
    httpClient.close();
}
```

This gave me the response that I needed, thanks a lot Richard, I never would've figured that out as a new user to flutter.

Comment: No problem - you're welcome. Glad you were able to work around what is almost certainly a server problem.

Answer (score 1):

**1st.** If you are using **http.post** you don't need to specify the application/json header all over again. Can you try removing **headers:header**.
**2do.** Please double check the body is in json format. 
Simple example using http.post

```
              const Map<String, String> header = {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
              };
              var res = await http.post(
                  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                  body: {'title': 'foo', 'body': 'bar', 'userId': '222110011'});
              print(res.body);
```

See that I'm not sending the http header.
Hope this help.

Comment: Note that the way you are using a `Map` as the body will result in sending the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is *not* what the OP wants