# Flutter Httpheaders invalid content error

Tags: flutter

Please help me, i try to call API from Client but application/json not read the content type

[image]

Comment: Try this code in your headers `headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json'
              'Content-Type":"application/json',
        },`

Comment: I already try this your code, but still messege invalid content error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter: Content-type must be application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893376/flutter-content-type-must-be-application-json)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code! :)